# Using MATLAB's solve function to find solution to system of equations

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am having trouble solving a system of equations. I have three equations with a known solution and three unknowns in each equation. However, when I use the `solve` function in MATLAB, it returns with the error that I have six equations and three variables.

A snippet of my code:

```
syms V0 T0 X0
A=(g*X0/(2*V0^2*cos(T0)^2)-tan(T0))==a;
B=(tan(T0)-g*X0/(V0^2*cos(T0)^2))==b;
C=(-g/(2*V0^2*cos(T0)^2))==c;

soln=solve([A,B,C],[V0,T0,X0]);
```

I have already calculated scalar values for `a`, `b`, and `c`. `g` is a constant. 
I am not sure why it is returning that I have six equations.

Comment: Please provide runnable code that defines `a`, `b`, etc. Also, edit to indicate exactly what error results, in full. Lastly, what `version` of Matlab are you using? Are you looking at the documentation for your version or what's online? If you have an old version you'll need to use `solve(A,B,C,V0,T0,X0);`, which works fine in the latest release as well.

Answer (score 0):

V0^2 means its a quadratic equation. You could solve for V0^2 as a variable. Set V0^2 = J0 and solve for J0 instead.

```
soln=solve([A,B,C],[J0,T0,X0]);
```

Then its three linear equations with three variables.

Once you get value of J0, then you need to solve for V0^2 = J0.

Comment: I just realized one more thing. You need to convert cos(T0) ^2 to sec(T0)^2 and then convert that to tan(T0)^2. Then you should get all the tan(T0) into one type - either tan T0, tan2T0 or TanTo^2.  Then you need to set W0 equal to that Tan T0 type and solve the equation  using       Soln= solve[A,B,C],[J0,W0,Xo]